# How to use vim to facilitate class definitions in sqlalchemy models?

Tags: python, class, vim, automation, sqlalchemy

I'm defining database-classes for SQLAlchemy, like so:

```py
class People(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    haircolor = Column(Text)
    height = Column(Numeric)

    def __init__(self, id, name, haircolor, height):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.haircolor = haircolor
        self.height = height
```

Writing this out manually is tedious repeated work for many tables. Since the structure of the class-definitions is always the same, there must be a way to configure vim to write a part of the definition for you, e.g. when adding the columns the init-function is automagically defined at the same time.

What are the tools vim provides to facilitate automation of somewhat complex code structures?

Comment: It's not realy what you are looking for but [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) can insert predefined snippets and can "react" on some input. Depending how complex your needs are it might not be the right tool.

Comment: Actually this is pretty exactly what I was looking for. I was not expecting something readymade and [python.snippets](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sirver/ultisnips/trunk/view/head:/UltiSnips/python.snippets) only needs a few adaptions to work with SQLAlchemy. @ingo-karkat's answer was later, but more extensive, so I'll give him the internet points. Thanks to you though for the initial correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Comment: I went for [UltiSnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) and added [python.snippets](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sirver/ultisnips/trunk/view/head:/UltiSnips/python.snippets)

Answer (score 0):

**Author's note/solution:**

This can be done with [UltiSnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) together with [python.snippets](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sirver/ultisnips/trunk/view/head:/UltiSnips/python.snippets). Additionally to the answers above, here's how I've extended python.snippets to work with the code-example in the question.

To create a SQLAlchemy specific class as in the example above, add the following code to the python.snippets file (Usually located at .vim/UltiSnips/python.snippets):

```py
########################################
# Custom snippets                      #
########################################

global !p

def write_init_body_sa(args, parents, snip):
    parents = [p.strip() for p in parents.split(",")]
    parents = [p for p in parents if p != 'object']

    for arg in args:
        snip += "self.%s = %s" % (arg, arg)

def write_sqlalchemy_columns(args, parents, snip):
   parents = [p.strip() for p in parents.split(",")]
   parents = [p for p in parents if p != 'object']

   for p in parents:
       snip += "__tablename__ = '%s'" % (p.lower())

   for arg in args:
       snip += "%s = Column()" % (arg)


endglobal

snippet saclass "SQLAlchemy class" b
class ${1:MyClass}(${2:Base}):`!p
snip >> 1
snip.rv = ""
args = get_args(t[3])
write_sqlalchemy_columns(args, t[1], snip)
`

    def __init__(self$3):`!p
snip.rv = ""
snip >> 2

args = get_args(t[3])
write_init_body_sa(args, t[2], snip)
`
     $0
endsnippet
```